# Where to download Edge 44

Tags: browser

I have to debug one issue for bug report for Edge 44 I have on my PC Edge 84. How can I install older version of Edge browser on my PC? I have BrowserStack but it does not offer that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling Chromium Edge on Windows sets it back to Edge 44!